# Python UDP client Ephemeral Reception Port

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I have a multi threaded python application communicating with a separate service trough UDP.

Each thread is similar, at some point need a response from the separate service.

So practically for each thread I create e new client socket and start to communicate. The problem is on the server side each UDP packet seems to come from the same reception port thus this create problem on the client side on who receives whose message.

How can I enforce the socket to use a different ephemeral reception port for each instance in the same program different threads?

Thanks!

Comment: is this on a local LAN or through some NAT mechanism?

Comment: it is on local LAN, err it is an ubuntu vmware machine with the network interface set to 'bridged'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `connect()` each UDP socket to it's target. That way the ephemeral ports will be fixed (and different) for each thread.

Comment: Thanks! Does not seem to randomize the ephemeral ports between instances yet, give me a little time to create a reduced test case and try again just to be sure it's not my fault.

Comment: Ok works on windows, however on windows works also connectionless (with sendto), but is interesting to know we can actually ask connection (I wander what is doing python here since UDP is connectionless) then send. Now I don't know what happens on my ubuntu machine but I will check later.

Comment: Basically `connect()`-ing UDP socket restricts it to talking to only one destination - sort of a filter (and a speedup - kernel bypasses some logic for connected UDP sockets).